# Read Error Rate is more than 5000... Do I need to replace my Hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

After searching the solutions in askubuntu, I found that I should replace the HDD, but as I know that SMART test is just for reference, because difference vendors has different standard, it makes me confused.

So, please forgive me for asking the repeated question "do I need to replace my HDD?"

Actually, I have finished the SMART test and it said Overall Assessment failed, in this situation (screen capture attached for your reference), do I need to replace the HDD?

Many thanks!!

[image: Images for reference...Please help....]

Comment: From the quick look at that drive, I would say yes it needs to be replaced.  You can still run `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sd?` to see if all the read failures are indeed happening.

Comment: Look at the smart error logs to get more detail on the error.  Rerun the self test and see if it still fails.

Comment: These are all great suggestions, but if you have any data on it that you value back it up FIRST!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `smartmontools`.  `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`

Then run `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdX`  **(X = your drive's letter)** to get all the data concerning the disk.  You will see more detailed information about possible failures.

Run `sudo smartctl --test=short /dev/sdX` to actually test the drive.  If there are failures, the short test will reveal them.  If not, replace **short** with **long**.  This will take longer but it will possibly reveal failures the short one didn't.

Any failures reported by those tests are reliable and do mean you have to replace the disk.

Comment: Thanks :) It helps me a lot, I will try it before I go to buy the new HDD.

Comment: any equivalent tool in windows?