# How can I fix hdd's health

Tags: hard-drive, smart

[image: Hard Drive SMART test results window]

Hi everyone. I need your help. Recently I checked my HDD via "Disks"
and saw that there are many problems in "Worst" column and in "Type" column many attributes are pre-fail and old-age. It seems like after some time my HDD may not work. I need to fix them and use my hard drive as much as  possible. Can I do it? thanks

I use Ubuntu 16.04 amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding; I got confused the first time I ran these tests, too. But there's nothing to worry about; despite the scary-sounding terms, the results are totally fine (don't believe me, though -- read the "Assessment" column and the test summaries at the top of the window).

The "Worst" column simply lists the worst allowable value for that specific test, and has nothing to do with your hard drive's actual results (which are all good -- again, see the "Assessment" column next to each test).

Likewise, "Pre-fail" and "Old Age" in the "Type" column simply tell you what kind of test it is -- those terms don't say anything about your hard drive *unless it actually failed one of those tests* (which it didn't).

If you want to see what the results window looks like for a drive that actually failed a test, see this question: [Read Error Rate is more than 5000... Do I need to replace my Hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825779/read-error-rate-is-more-than-5000-do-i-need-to-replace-my-hard-disk) ... notice the big, red, bold **SELF-TEST FAILED** message.

But your results show that your hard drive is totally OK and there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I hope you're right). because, you know, HDDs and the files in it are really important.

Comment: If the contents are really important you should have a backup, either in another drive or remotely in a cloud service.